# Please explain to me why this function is not recursive

Tags: c++, recursion

My instructor insists that I am not writing recursive functions but has not provided any explanation of why my functions are not recursive. I've been researching recursive functions for weeks now but apparently still do not understand what makes a recursive function. As far as I am able to gather, a recursive function is any function which calls itself using a matching function call to the original.

Psuedo example:

```
bool foo(int someInt){
++someInt;
return foo(someInt);
}
```

Below is my latest function.

```
int LinkedList::sumR(int intIn){
    if(intIn == 0){
    if(head != NULL)
    curr = head;
    }  

    if (head != NULL){
        if(curr->next != NULL){
            intIn = intIn + curr->data;
            curr = curr->next;
            return sumR(intIn);
        }  
        else
        {              
            intIn = intIn + curr->data;
        }

    return intIn;
    }
return intIn;
}
```

I'm completely lost at this point.

### Update

After emailing my instructor, they responded that for a function to be recursive it must accept a class or struct pointer as a parameter (as far as they're concerned, I guess).

Comment: Your function is recursive, who said it isn't?

Comment: Those functions look recursive to me, though there are some issues with them (the first one never terminates and will trigger a stack overflow, the second one never makes a recursive call unless the input is zero).

Comment: My instructor did. 

"how did you do recursion with only one int as parameter? Please study module 2 for recursive solution."

Comment: The `curr` in your code looks odd: is it a class member?

Comment: Yes it is a class member.

Comment: Consider telling your instructor that you've sought outside advice and you've been told "This is recursive".

Comment: _Recursion_ is defined as `the process of defining a function or calculating a number by the repeated application of an algorithm.` ... You don't need a function to take input to be recursive, example: `void recurse() { recurse(); }` .. Mind you that will cause a stack overflow, but it's still recursive. Ask your instructor if maybe he's just looking for something else in your answer (e.g. it's recursive, but he wants the branching (`if..else` statements) written differently) ..

Comment: Your function is recursive. But it is not a recursive solution to the problem your instructor wants you to solve , which I presume is finding the sum of the elements of a linked list. Your function uses a class member or static object (`curr`) to record the current scan position; a recursive solution (to this problem) would pass the current scan position as a parameter. (It might also use an accumulator argument, particularly if it were trying to be tail-recursive.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any recursive method will include the following **three basic elements**:

1. A test to stop or continue the recursion.
2. **An end case** that terminates the recursion.
3. A recursive call(s) that continues the recursion.

Your first example is missing #2

https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-recursion/

Answer (score 1):

Without a mathematical definition it is hard to tell, but I think what your instructor expects is that you implement this as a pure function, not relying on any state external to the function (such as your variable named `cur`).

e.g. take the factorial function (5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1)

```
int fact(n) = { 1 if n == 1 else n * fact(n-1) }
```

If I implement this the way you implemented your list sum above

```
prod = 1
fact(n) {
    if (n > 1) {
       prod *= n;
       fact(n - 1);
    }
}
```

This second implementation relies on side-effects (the global state variable `prod`).

If your `LinkedList` is list of nodes `LinkedList::Node` (what your variable `cur` and `head` point to), then try to redefine your function as:

```
int LinkedList::sumR(LinkedList::node cur);
```

and call it with `sumR(list->head);`